# Is there a difference between the Controller classes in MVC3 and MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created a project using ASP.NET MVC3. I now want to port it to MVC5. As I'm doing so, will I need to change the Controller classes in any specific ways? Are there different conventions or coding requirements between the two versions, or can I just copy and paste the C# code over without changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally they are the same. [This link gives a nice overview of the features](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/02/asp-net-mvc3-vs-mvc4-vs-mvc5.html) between the versions